# Undefined index while fetching the cookie value after closing browser

Tags: php, cookies

i am trying to implement remember me feature. It is working well but whenever i close my browser the cookie is deleted and showing error:  Undefined index

my code for setting cookie is: `setCookie("rememberme", $cookie);`

the file that set the cookie and the file that is fetching are in the same location.

checked in more than one browser same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you specify when the cookie is to expire it will automatically expire when the browser window is closed. The third parameter of `setcookie()` allows you to specify the expiration of the cookie:

```
// Cookie expires in one year
setCookie("rememberme", $cookie, strtotime('+1 year'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with domain parameter

**Syntax**

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain, secure, httponly);
```

Example code

```
 <?php
    setCookie("rememberme", $cookie, strtotime('+1 year'),"/");
 ?>
```